# Deleting Contacts from Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to be able use the Graph API from an Azure function to delete and update Contacts in a user's Outlook.

I am able to add Contacts to the users with no problem from the Azure function.

However, when I later want to delete or update a Contact, it seems I am only able to do this is if I know the Contact's ID number, using:

```
DELETE /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/contactFolders/{id}/contacts/{id}
```

However, I will not know the {id} as I am hoping to do this asynchronously by sending a queue message, rather than having an interactive session open.

Really I would like to be able to say something like: delete the contact that has the email address 'firstname.lastname@domain.com' if the Notes field contains "This Contact was added by Blah Script" (which I will have added to all the Contacts I added automatically).

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is always a two-step process.

1. You need to first query Graph to find the `id`:

   ```
   GET /contacts?$filter=emailAddresses/any(a:a/address eq 'someone@somplace.com')
   ```
2. You then need to iterate over the results and issue a `DELETE` for each contact you want to delete:

   ```
   DELETE /contacts/{id}
   ```

Comment: Thanks. Good to have it confirmed.